# Allow Rcpp functions in DEoptim for R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I have been using DEoptim for some time to test different parameters for a hydrology algorithm.  The code is mainly written in R, but there is a function written in Rcpp.  If I run DEoptim in non-parallel mode, it runs fine, but if I run in parallel mode (i.e. paralleltype=1) the code returns an error saying it can't find my Rcpp function.  So the Rcpp function looks like this:

```
loadcppfunctions <- function() {
eastfunc <<- 'NumericMatrix eastC(NumericMatrix e, NumericMatrix zerocolmatrix, NumericMatrix zerorowmatrix) {
int ecoln = e.ncol();
int ecolnlessone = ecoln - 1;
int erown = e.nrow();
int erownlessone = erown - 1;

NumericMatrix eout(e.nrow(),e.ncol()) ;
for (int j = 0;j < ecoln;j++) {
if (j > 0) {
eout(_,j) = e(_,j-1);
} else {
eout(_,j) = e(_,0);
}
}
eout(_,0) = zerocolmatrix(_,0);
return eout;
}'
eastC <<- cppFunction(eastfunc)
}
```

and then I just use:

```
loadcppfunctions()
```

Later in the code I call this function as follows:

```
movefdrerunoff <- eastC(fdrerunoff, zerocolmatrix, zerorowmatrix)
```

As I say, it all works fine - but if I run DEoptim as follows:

```
ans <- DEoptimone(Calibrate,lower,upper,DEoptim.control(trace=TRUE,parallelType=1,parVar=c(parVarnames),packages=c("raster","rgdal","maptools","matrixcalc","Rcpp","RcppArmadillo")))
```

It fails saying:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  7 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "eastC"
```

So how can I make DEoptim see this function when all the other R based functions are fine.

Thanks, Antony Walker

Comment: If I remember correctly, the canonical solution is to build a package.

Comment: And RcppDE is the port fo DEoptim to Rcpp which allows you to pass a compiled function.

Comment: I built a package called moveCpp - containing the code above loadcppfunctions.  The package loads but it still says it can't see eastC - any ideas how I build the package correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that by adding the Rcpp function inside the main DEoptim function (Calibrate) worked.  The Calibrate function looked like:

```
Calibrate <- function(x) {
eastfunc <<- 'NumericMatrix eastC(NumericMatrix e, NumericMatrix zerocolmatrix, NumericMatrix zerorowmatrix) {
int ecoln = e.ncol();
int ecolnlessone = ecoln - 1;
int erown = e.nrow();
int erownlessone = erown - 1;

NumericMatrix eout(e.nrow(),e.ncol()) ;
for (int j = 0;j < ecoln;j++) {
if (j > 0) {
eout(_,j) = e(_,j-1);
} else {
eout(_,j) = e(_,0);
}
}
eout(_,0) = zerocolmatrix(_,0);
return eout;
}'
eastC <<- cppFunction(eastfunc)

cmax <<- x[1]
Cr <<- x[2]
Cl <<- x[3]
Crb <<- x[4]
Clb <<- x[5]
returnflowriver <<- x[6]
returnflowland <<- x[7]
kd <<- x[8]
startyear()
-NashSutcliffe
}
```

and then running DEoptim as:

```
ans <- DEoptimone(Calibrate,lower,upper,DEoptim.control(trace=TRUE,parallelType=1,parVar=c(parVarnames),packages=c("raster","rgdal","maptools","matrixcalc","Rcpp","RcppArmadillo","moveCpp")))
```

Comment: I would not consider this a good solution. Presumably you use parallelization to speed-up the optimization. This compiles the Rcpp function at each call of you `Calibrate` function, which is time consuming.

Comment: I can see your point - however, my calibrate function takes an hour/hours to run so a second lost is marginal.